# Multiple Relation Item in Netlify CMS

Tags: netlify-cms

I've two collections

1. Posts
2. Categories

In my case, each post can have multiple categories.

Hence the way I'm setting it is
Post has a field of type List which is further a Field of type Relation.
Is there a straightforward way to specify this relationship?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The [Relation widget](https://www.netlifycms.org/docs/widgets/#relation) has a `multiple` option that, when set to `true`, will do just that without having to rely on a `list` widget.

eg:

```
fields:
  - label: 'Categories'
    name: 'categories'
    widget: 'relation'
    collection: 'categories'
    value_field: '{{slug}}'
    display_fields: [title]
    search_fields: [title]
    multiple: true
```